# Clustered Index Entity Framework

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6

When I Create the azure database with Entity Framework model first pattern, then the creation works. But when I want to save the database I get the following error:
"Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again."

I updated entity Framework to Version 6.1.2. But still get the same eroor. Do you have any idea?

Comment: As the error says : every table in SQL Azure **must have** a clustering key. By default, in SQL Server (and SQL Azure), the **primary key** will be the clustering key; so I presume you have *at least one table* that doesn't define a **primary key** - that's what you need to fix!

Comment: I don't have a table without a Primary key. Entity Framework creates a Primary key for every table.